# webpack 3 ModuleConcatenationPlugin

Tags: webpack

добавил webpack 3, но нет результата в плагине ModuleConcatenationPlugin, размер пакета bundle.js не меняется, 
?

Comment: Реформулируйте вопрос и укажите код - Ошибку... как мы можем помочь без данных...

Comment: нет ошибки и результата нет, размер  bundle.js не меняется

Comment: а код в котором вы работаете есть ?

Answer (score 0):

Включить преобразование синтаксиса модуля ES6 в другой тип модуля.
Установка этого параметра в значение false не преобразует модули.
в файле .babelrc add ["es2015", {"modules": false}]

```
{
  "presets": [["es2015", {"modules": false}], "stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": []
}
```